# Next Command - forwards onto the next Excel Line while clearing form fields

Tags: vba, excel, button

I would like to have my Next Command Button when pushed to pull the information from the form and input it into my Excel Spreadsheet.  Although I would like to add a warning 'Selecting Next will Save Current Data and Clear Form' Is this okay?  If selected Yes then the form clears and the user is able to enter another persons information.

Would someone assist in the code?

Comment: That seems fine to me.

Comment: Assist? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So many different things that I am starting completely over now

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Next_Command_Click()
    Do
        nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow + 1
        TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
    Loop Until NCCL.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = "" Or NCCL.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = Me.PatientIdentifier_Text.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Previous_Command_Click()
    Do
        nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow - 1
        TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
    Loop Until nCurrentRow = 1 Or NCCL.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value =  Me.PatientIdentifier_Text.Value
End Sub